# How to create a website using Node js and Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to create website using **Node js, expressJS**

Is any way or similar to **Python Flask Jinja templating** for website creation using Nodejs and expressJs

**New to Node js back end**

Create dynamic Website using node js and express js with Bootstrap or Using any other Css Framework For Fornt End it is Blog website.

Answer (score 0):

For my view, you need to use nodeJs with exoress.js for creating API 
and using this API you need to integrate front-end (angular, vuejs, reactjs etc.. )

if you want to make only using nodeJs then you need to use ejs template or something else.

Comment: @ chirag sorathiya
Only using node js ,Express Js and bootstrap for fornt end(UI part only).
It is a blog web app with MongoDB for database.